# monodb.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at monodb.js:2:25

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, deployment, node-modules

```
    const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb")
    const url='mongodb://localhost:27017'
    const client=new MongoClient(url);
    async function getdata(){
        let result=await client.connect();
        let db=result.db("first")
        let collection=db.collection("c1");
        let res=await collection.find({}).toArray()
        console.log(collection.find({}).toArray())
    }
    getdata()
```

I'm getting this error:

```
monodb.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at monodb.js:1:1)
```

on this line

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb")
```

I've installed mongodb nodejs driver what can i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given 2 different error messages. In your title the error says:

```
monodb.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at monodb.js:2:25
```

But in your question you say the error is:

```
monodb.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at monodb.js:1:1)
```

Either way the most likely cause is you are trying to use [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#require) `require` statements but you have defined the `"type": "module"` properties in your `package.json`. Or you are trying to use the [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#introduction) approach to importing modules by using `import` statements without defining `"type": "module"`.

If you have defined the `"type": "module"` properties in your `package.json` then you will have to adopt the [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#introduction) approach to importing modules by using `import` statements. You can't mix `require` statements in a project defined as `"type": "module"`. If you want to keep using the `require` keyword you will have to remove the `"type": "module"` from your `package.json`.

Try this instead:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
```

Here are the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/languages/javascript/mongodb-and-npm-tutorial) which are a great resource for starting off with MongoDB on Node.js. I suggest you follow.

If you want to use [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#introduction) modules in your clinet-side JavaScript (i.e. in the browser) then make sure you add the `type="module"` attribute in the `<script>` tag like so:

```
<script type="module" src="myfilename.js"></script>
```

Please note: bear in mind you won't be able to `import` packages in Node and then use them on the client-side.

Comment: i've added "type":"module" in package.json file but i'm still getting the error

Comment: If you have that added then you will need to use `import` statements throughout. You can't use `require` statements (without workarounds).

Comment: ```import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

const url='mongodb://localhost:27017'
const client=new MongoClient(url);
async function getdata(){
    let result=await client.connect();
    let db=result.db("first")
    let collection=db.collection("c1");
    let res=await collection.find({}).toArray()
    console.log(collection.find({}).toArray())
}
getdata()```  i'm using  **import** statement still getting same error

Comment: That code looks fine. You have `"type": "module"` defined in your `package.json` and are using `import` to import the `MongoClient`. All good. Now... are you using `require` elsewhere in your code , because you can't. You must use `import` throughout. For example, how are you importing `express` etc. Also, did you know you named a file `monodb.js` , just incase you think it's name `mongodb.js`?

Comment: no i'm not using

Comment: Can you post the error message that you are now receiving.?The whole message please.

Comment: monodb.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at monodb.js:1:1)

Comment: i'm getting this error only in browser in terminal this code is working

Comment: That explains everything, thank you. If you want to use modules in your client-side JavaScript then you will need to use `<script type="module" src="filename.js"></script>`. I will update answer.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "mongodb". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".                                                                         now i'm getting this error can you help

Comment: I can help you resolve the paths but you won't be able to use `MongoClient` in your client-side JavaScript if that is your intention?

Comment: What does that mean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255230/discussion-between-jqueeny-and-mm-m).